# Padding leading Zeros within a for-each

Tags: xml, xslt

Using XSLT I have the following code which currently works to create a date.

```
<xsl:for-each select="release-date/year | release-date/month | release-date/day">
  <xsl:if test="position() !=1">-</xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/
</xsl:for-each>
```

Sample Output: `2008-5-14`, `2008-5-1`

I am trying to modify this code so that it will pad the release month and day with leading zeroes if they are a single digit. Thus

Desired Output: `2008-05-14`, `2008-05-01`

I have tried using `format-number()` and `substring(string(), 2)` as seen on similar questions, but either my syntax is incorrect when implementing, or they do not work with the `|` I am using.

Comment: For XSLT questions please always say which version you are using, as the answer will very often be different for XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Why would the `<xsl:for-each>` be relevant? It seems to me a simpler question could be asked instead: "Given the string "2008-5-14" how can I pad with zeros?".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="release-date/year" /> 
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(release-date/month, '-00')"/>
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(release-date/day, '-00')"/>
```

Comment: A clever way to approach it I hadn't  considered.  Brilliant, and this works.